# Visual Studio "The debug worker process exited unexpectedly" on the same breakpoint every run

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2019, vulkan

I'm trying to debug my vulkan code. However, I get a visual studio debugger crash if I place a hit point within this loop (code below). I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 16.4. Things I have tried so far:

- Rebuild
- Clean
- Repair Install
- New Install
- Visual Studio Preview (16.5)

I don't think it's code specific, but here's the code. If it makes a difference, it's during a vulkan command buffer record, but I really don't think it's vulkan related.

EDIT: Now exhibited same behaviour in a completely different place in my code. I have no idea what the common factor is.

```
for  (VulkanObjectAttachment * voa : md->contents)
{
int i = 0;
for (auto x : currentPipeline->shader->shaderSpecificFeatures)
{
    int setIndex = (i * HE2_RenderBackend::imageCount) + frameIndex;

    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(*commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, currentPipeline->pipelineLayout, x.first, 1, &voa->specificFeatureDescriptorSets[setIndex], 0, nullptr);
    i++;
}

vkCmdDrawIndexed(*commandBuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(vma->indices), 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

}

First, the busy message appears here, and you can't click anything
[image: The Busy message]

Then, this error message appears, about 15 seconds later
[image]

Comment: Please try to check the option`Use Managed Compatibility Mode`  by `Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->General`.

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestions haven't worked, but I've tried moving past the sections of code where the crash occurs for now

Comment: What helped me was to close the Autos window when debugging. With the Autos window open I received the same error, after I closed it the error was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> Visual Studio “The debug worker process exited unexpectedly” on the
>   same breakpoint every run

This problem is usually caused when you are debugging code and loading multiple instances of the same module in the application domain. To troubleshot this issue, you can try these steps:

**One**

1) check the option `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` by `Tools-->options-->Debugging-->General`.

**Two**

1) Remove all the breakpoints first by `Debug-->Delete All Breakpoints`.

2) close Project and then reopen VS

3) run your project first without any breakpoints and after that, put any breakpoints  you want to debug your project

Hope it could help you.